# SQL Command Default Value

Tags: mysql, sql, default-value

In my Ms Sql command, I want to get sum of C.HEIGHT's values

```
 SELECT SUM(C.HEIGHT) 
 FROM CIHAZ AS C 
 INNER JOIN ILISKI AS I ON I.REL_CIHAZ=C.ID 
 WHERE I.REL_DOLAP=2
```

This value is returning NULL but I want to give Default Value to  sum(C.HEIGHT) .

How can we provide this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the default value?

Comment: In TSQL it can be ISNULL(SUM(C.HEIGHT),0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` to provide a default value in case the column value is NULL, like so:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(C.HEIGHT), yourdefaultvalue)
FROM CIHAZ AS C 
INNER JOIN ILISKI AS I ON I.REL_CIHAZ=C.ID 
WHERE I.REL_DOLAP=2
```

`COALESCE` is an ANSI standard function, and you can use it in the way shown above in MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: Quick link to `COALESCE` MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190349.aspx) but, since you're aggregating over all results, you're probably getting `NULL` because there are no rows. In that case, you need to wrap the *entire* query as a subquery to get `COALESCE` to act the way that we want:

```
SELECT COALESCE( 
(SELECT SUM(C.HEIGHT) 
 FROM CIHAZ AS C 
 INNER JOIN ILISKI AS I ON I.REL_CIHAZ=C.ID 
 WHERE I.REL_DOLAP=2),
0 /* <-- default */) as Result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace any `NULL`s inline with `coalesce`, as shree.pat18 has said.

Although, according to SQL standards, `NULL` values will be ignored during aggregation unless there are *no matching rows at all* as stated here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html

> SUM() returns NULL if there were no matching rows.

That means that you do **not** need to do this:

```
select sum(coalesce(c.height, 0))....
```

(just in case you or anybody else was wondering).

So a `COALESCE` around the entire query will do it, as Damien_The_Unbeliever shows.

```
select coalesce(<query goes here>, 0)....
```